# Bootstrap container too wide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Quite simple problem; bootstrap container inside navbar is too wide, causing a horizontal scrollbar as it expands the body.

The page in question can be found [here](http://lasca.nl/), the theme it's built on is [this](http://www.themetosia.com/Rocket/UpdateV3/Light/what.html) one.

What baffles me is that the CSS for both seems to be equal and the computed values Chrome dev tools return are the same. Would be awesome if someone would be able to find the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer: A `.row` with no `.container` around it caused it

Comment: i had this issue and it was for the same reason.

Comment: Also in Bootstrap 5. You can use container-fluid

Answer (score 1):

Current accepted answer seams to be spot on (look for `.row` with not `.container` around it).

However looking for it manually can be slow, so here's super quick&dirty jQuery script to run in the console:

```
$.each($('.row'), function (key, value) {
    if (!($(this).parent().hasClass('container') || $(this).parent().hasClass('container-fluid'))) {
        console.log('Check .row ' + key);
        console.log( $(this) );
    }
});
```

It will return few .row IDs and preview

```
[Log] Check .row 14
[Log] w [<div class="row">] (1)
[Log] Check .row 16
[Log] w [<div class="row">] (1)
```

Just expand the node in the console and easily identify which one is the offending party.